# Show that $E[X\vert \sigma(\mathcal{H},\mathcal{G})]=E[X\vert \mathcal{G}]$

Tags: probability-theory, conditional-expectation

Show that $E[X\vert \sigma(\mathcal{H},\mathcal{G})]=E[X\vert \mathcal{G}]$ where  $ X \in L^1(\Omega,\mathcal{F},\mathbb{P})$ and $\mathcal{G},\mathcal{H}$ are sub-sigma algebras of $\mathcal{F}$ and the sigma algebra $\mathcal{H}$ is independent of $\sigma(\sigma(X),\mathcal{G})$

My Attempt:

To show that $E[X\vert \mathcal{G}]=E[X\vert \sigma(\mathcal{H},\mathcal{G})]$, its enough to show that $E[X\vert \sigma(\mathcal{H},\mathcal{G})]$ is $\mathcal{G}$-measurable and that for $A \in \mathcal{G}$
the following is true

$E[X \mathcal{1}_{A}]=EE[X\vert \sigma(\mathcal{H},\mathcal{G})] \mathcal{1}_A]$

This is true since  $EE[X\vert \sigma(\mathcal{H},\mathcal{G})] \mathcal{1}_A]=EE[X\mathcal{1}_A\vert \sigma(\mathcal{H},\mathcal{G})] ]=E[X \mathcal{1}_A]$

I cant show precisely that $E[X\vert \sigma(\mathcal{H},\mathcal{G})]$ is also $\mathcal{G}$ measurable instead of being measurable just wrt the larger sigma field $\sigma(\mathcal{H},\mathcal{G})$.

Can somebody help?

Comment: @Sisyphus What is wrote is not true! We dont even use the assumptions in the question.

Comment: Oh sorry, I misread.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can check [this](http://statweb.stanford.edu/~adembo/stat-310b/lnotes.pdf) on page number 159. He has proved it with great explanation

Comment: Link is broken.